# React Monaco Editor trying to load URL from Local files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, electron, monaco-editor

I'm using Monaco (`@monaco-editor/react`) for a code editor in a react-electron typescript application. When I simply `import Editor from '@monaco-editor/react';` and then add an `Editor` component to React, I'm getting the error

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
D:\<My project directory>\https:\cdn.jsdelivr.net\npm\monaco-editor@0.36.1\min\vs\editor\editor.main.js'
```

which I'm assuming means it's trying to load a URL but it is somehow getting added to the path of my local directory. I checked the URL and it does in fact lead to a Javascript file. Does anyone know how to get rid of the local path at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to use Monaco Editor as an npm package. To do this do the following:

```
import { loader } from "@monaco-editor/react";
import * as monaco from "monaco-editor";
loader.config({ monaco });
```

There instructions in the readme for Monaco Editor for doing just this [here](https://github.com/suren-atoyan/monaco-react#use-monaco-editor-as-an-npm-package):